# wxpython: Mouse Up event fires wrong

Tags: wxpython, mouseevent

I ran into a problem where the wx.EVT_LEFT_UP event seems to fire wrong, or at least, I find it very counter-intuitive.

I want to call a function when I down-click on one panel, hold the button and then fire a function when up-click on an other panel.

Consider the following code:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # left panel
        lPan = wx.Panel(panel)
        lPan.SetBackgroundColour('#9C4141')
        lPan.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, lambda e, p='left': self.onLeftDown(e, p))
        lPan.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, lambda e, p='left': self.onLeftUp(e, p))

        # right panel
        rPan = wx.Panel(panel)
        rPan.SetBackgroundColour('#415C9C')
        rPan.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, lambda e, p='right': self.onLeftDown(e, p))
        rPan.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, lambda e, p='right': self.onLeftUp(e, p))

        # box sizer
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(lPan, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        hbox.Add(rPan, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Show()

    def onLeftDown(self, e, panel):
        print('Mouse down on {} panel'.format(panel))

    def onLeftUp(self, e, panel):
        print('Mouse up on {} panel'.format(panel))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Down and Up click', size=(200, 150))
    app.MainLoop()
```

This would work e.g. with JavaScript just fine, as the Element bind to the events would react to Down and Up clicks independently. Here however, it seems, that the Up event fires only for the panel which was Down-clicked before. (see picture).

[image]

As you can see, the Up-event is fired for the left panel instead for the right panel. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: Hello, on Windows, both on 2.7/wxPython 2.9 and on 3.6.2/wxPython 4.0 your example works as you expected (down left/up right). You can use the [WIT](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool), insert the two-liner before you enter the main loop, browse to the panels and activate the Event viewer to see all events for the two panels in realtime.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the inspector. I used it and for me there is really no mouse up event (or other events than motion and setcursor) on the right panel after the drag. I also use version wxPython 4 ('4.0.0b1 osx-cocoa (phoenix)' to be exact), so it seems to be a macOS implementation bug.

Answer (score 1):

As nepix32 pointed out, this might be a macOS related implementation bug, so I try the following workaround.

Mouse enter and leave gets detected accurately, so I guess I bind those to track the latest entered panel and store it in the parent. For an Up-click on any panel, I handle whatever I want to do with the stored panel.

This is what I mean (works as expected):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
#import wx.lib.inspection

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # parent for left and right panels
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#759538')

        self.lastEntered = None

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        # setup some child panels
        for name in ['left', 'middle', 'right']:
            pan = wx.Panel(panel, name=name)
            pan.SetBackgroundColour('#404040')
            # bind events
            pan.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onLeftDown)
            pan.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.onLeftUp)
            pan.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onEnter)
            # put in sizer
            hbox.Add(pan, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=5)

        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.Show()

    def onLeftDown(self, e):
        panel = e.GetEventObject()
        print('Mouse down on '+panel.GetName())

    def onLeftUp(self, e):
        panel = e.GetEventObject()
        print('Mouse up on '+panel.GetName())
        # the actual up panel
        if self.lastEntered:
            print('Actual up on '+self.lastEntered.GetName())

    def onEnter(self, e):
        panel = e.GetEventObject()
        self.lastEntered = panel
        print('Entered '+panel.GetName())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Down and Up click', size=(200, 150))
    #wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: From what I can ascertain, once you have `down` clicked, the events are locked onto the clicked widget, for `click` purposes. You are correct that you will get `Enter` plus `Leave`,`Motion` etc but the mouse `up` is still locked to the original mouse `down` widget. You can check this by checking the `Id` or `Name` of the event. Your solution will work for 2 panels because it's either or but if you try to implement your solution for more than 2 panels, you will have to try to ascertain a cursor position relative to the panel position which can be complicated. (Linux wx 3.0.2.0 gtk2 (classic))

Comment: I have edited my answer to give an example. It works for multiple panels. Could you check if this works on Linux? I really need this to work on all Desktop platforms.

Comment: No it fails. Entered left,
Mouse down on left,
Mouse up on left,
Actual up on left.
When click on left and release on middle

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Very discouraging to see 3 different event behaviours on 3 different os :-(